# Background-image: linear-gradient not working on Safari (OS X)

Tags: css, safari, webkit, background-image

I'm trying to style a 100% width div with a dark background a green raster. It works fine in all the browsers, except for Safari on OS X (works fine on iOS). I have no clue why it isn't working and can't seem to find an answer somewhere on the internet.

This is my styling:

```
background-color: #434343;
background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 24%, rgba(50,205,50, 0.3) 25%, rgba(50,205,50, 0.3) 26%, transparent 27%, transparent 74%, rgba(50,205,50, 0.3) 75%, rgba(50,205,50, 0.3) 76%, transparent 77%, transparent), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 24%, rgba(50,205,50, 0.3) 25%, rgba(50,205,50, 0.3) 26%, transparent 27%, transparent 74%, rgba(50,205,50, 0.3) 75%, rgba(50,205,50, 0.3) 76%, transparent 77%, transparent);
background-size: 60px 60px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 200px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 200px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 200px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Does any of you have a clue why it only displays the dark background on Safari and not the green raster? Thnx a lot!

Comment: It works on Safari 13.0.2, just tested: https://angular-ivy-fzbiqs.stackblitz.io/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #E7E7E7 97%, #FFFFFF 98%);/* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
```

Also, check out the gradient generator

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Aready tried to prefix it with -webkit- but linear-gradient *shouldn't* need a prefix. Besides that, the solution, sadly enough, doesn't work. :-(